# Fixed width header and fluid images with isotope/masonry

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I have a fixed width header and loads of images on a page. I want to appear them same as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Image width is variable and can be up to 200px. I have tried following code but it doesn't work. Images overlap the header and there is a small space between the images.

```js
$(function() {
        $('.grid').isotope({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            percentPosition: true,
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: ''
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.container {
        width: 1024px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .header {
        width: 300px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: #0fa3c3;
        float: left;
    }
    .item {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.2.0/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="header"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.. I gave the header absolute position also.. and z-index of 2, try it now.

```js
$(function() {
        $('.grid').isotope({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            percentPosition: true,
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: ''
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.container {
        //width: 1024px;
        //margin: 0 auto;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .header {
        width: 300px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: #0fa3c3;
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .item {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.2.0/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="header"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @oserk This solution won't work for me because images are behind the header. Why did you comment the container class?